# Override the classpath in the MANIFEST.MF of a jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the classpath to override a file in a jar that is being run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708534/can-i-use-the-classpath-to-override-a-file-in-a-jar-that-is-being-run)

I have an application that is packed into a runnable jar file, this application use several external jar libraries including them into the classpath. The list of libraries is specified into the manifest.mf file of the main executable jar.

I want to let the user override the classpath contained into the manifest.mf by specifying a classpath from the command line(for example -cp), but I can' t make it work.

Though i pass the classpath with the option -cp, the classpath in the manifest file is not overridden ,  is there a way to override a classpath contained in the manifest file ? How?

Comment: What is the command used to execute the app? You don't ise both -cp and -jar, do you?

Comment: dont use the jar option.. just use cp and provide your main class name .. I think using the jar option will make the jvm take only the classpath provided in the jar..

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I have the same question. Using -cp without -jar worked for you? Is it add classpath entries to the one defined in the manifest? or, it overrides the manifest (so the manifest entries are not taken into account)?

Comment: If you use -cp the MANIFEST.MF in the jar is not considered ...